# Return model with laravel when it was created

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql-9.4

I need to send a new model saved as json to front but I can't see column organizationid in response

This is my model

```
class Organization extends Model
{
    protected $table = "core.organizations";
    protected $fillable = ['description'];
    public $primaryKey = "organizationid";
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and this is my function

```
public function saveOrganization(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $description = $request->input('description');
            $organization = new Organization();
            $organization->description = $description;
            $organization->save();
            if (!$organization) {
                throw new \Exception("No se guardo la organizacion");
            }           
            return response()->json([
            'organization' => $organization,
            ], 200);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Ha ocurrido un error al intentar guardar la organización',
            ], 200);
        }
    }
```

and this is response

```
{"organization":{"description":"Restobar"}}
```

How can I do?

Thanks you!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you've created a new object, and not retrieved one from the database, the only attributes it will know about are the ones that you set.

If you'd like to get the rest of the fields on the table, you will need to re-retrieve the object after you save it.

```
// create the new record.
// this instance will only know about the fields you set.
$organization = Organization::create([
    'description' => $description,
]);

// re-retrieve the instance to get all of the fields in the table.
$organization = $organization->fresh();
```

Comment: Thanks you @patricus!!!!, the method fresh() works and I see organizationid in the json response.

Answer (score 2):

```
$savedOrganization = Organization::create(
    [
        'description' => $description
    ]
);

return response()->json([
        'organization' => $savedOrganization,
        ], 200)
```

And this code is useless

```
if (!$organization) {
    throw new \Exception("No se guardo la organizacion");
}
```

Comment: `$organization->save()` returns boolean values, dude.

Comment: thanks but I see the same response {"organization":{"description":"Restobar"}}

Answer (score 1):

Something I notice on Laravel 7.x (which might be true for previous versions as well):

I tried handling both creating and updating of new object with save as follows:

```
public static function saveAnswers(\stdClass $answers) {
    if($answers->id) {
        $jsonObject = JsonObject::find($answers->id);
    } else {
        $jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    }
    $jsonObject->fill((array) $answers);
    $jsonObject->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    return $jsonObject->save();
}
```

This lead to return-value being boolean (true). I was bit baffled, because I had used saving and returning on other endpoints multiple times successfully before. Finally I discovered that returning $jsonObject->save() always returns boolean, but returning just $jsonObject AFTER SAVING returns mutated object! So basically do saving and returning of object on separate commands:

```
$jsonObject->save();
return $jsonObject;
```

Don't know what sort of witchery this is, but having worked with C# and JAVA projects I had gotten used to piping methods to first mutate class instance and finally the class instance being returned... Might be that PHP handles this workflow bit differently.