# Return Model of Newly created Multiple records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

I need to get the model of newly created records

```
$data = [['name' => 'john'], ['name' => 'Doe']];
$result = Model::insert($data);
```

But when I checked the `$result` variable it was Boolean.

How can I get the newly created records?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return model with laravel when it was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404630/return-model-with-laravel-when-it-was-created)

Answer (score 1):

using `fresh()` solved my problem

```
$data = [['name' => 'john'], ['name' => 'Doe']];
$result = Model::create($data);
$data = $result->fresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using insert you can use create, for example,

```
$data = [['name' => 'john'], ['name' => 'Doe']];
$result = Model::insert($data);//instead of this!
$result = Model::create($data);// use this,
```

then the $result keyword will return last created data.
if you are using,
`$result = $model->save();` method, you have to return $model variable. should not return $result, because it will give you the Boolean value only.